# LibGDX FrameBuffer no Transparency when drawing

Tags: libgdx, transparency, frame-buffer

I try to draw severeal `Sprites` to a `FrameBuffer`. The `Sprites` are PNGs with transparency. When I draw them directly to the screen it's fine. But when I draw on the `FrameBuffer` and then draw the resulting texture on the screen the transparent parts are cut out and the glBackground shines through. Any idea how to solve this?

Here is how I do it:

```
FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, width, height, false);
Sprite fboTexture = new Sprite(frameBufferObject.getColorBufferTexture());
fboTexture.flip(false, true);

fbo.begin();
batch.begin();
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.draw(sprite1, 0,0);
batch.draw(sprite2, 0,0);
batch.draw(sprite3, 0,0);
batch.end();
fbo.end();

batch.begin();
batch.draw(fboTexture, 0,0);
batch.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it myself. I simply change the blend function before drawing the `FrameBuffer`.I change it to `batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA)` and then change it back to `batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to enable blending in the batch

```
batch.enableBlending();
```

Comment: Blending is enabled by default and I never disabled it.

Comment: This should've been a comment..